# Large table joins small table oom

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hive

I have a large table, say `a`, with about 100 million rows. Keys may have duplicates. Some of the keys may have appear in over 1million rows. Another table, say `b`, has about 20 thousands rows, where keys are all unique. Although the rows in `b` are small, but the field of each row is big, say about 1M in average and 10M in max.

I am joining `a` with table `b` on `a.key = b.key`. However, it's always oom. What can I do to optimize the table join? Please help

Comment: broadcast the second one?

Comment: @Lamanus, Sorry for not describing the question cleary. I've edited it.
Although the rows in b are small, but the field of each row is big, say about 1M in average and 10M in max.